# Unable to upgrade to a newer distribution

Tags: upgrade

I was trying to upgrade my ubuntu version to 12.04 but it failed to get the last three packages out of 1525. I tried it many times but failed. Is there any way that I can download the three packages separately and continue with my system upgrade? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Selam

Comment: What have you done so far? What commands have you entered? is the system up to date?

Comment: What were the three packages that were failing? What version are you currently running?

Comment: What version are you starting with? See [UpgradeNotes](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes)

Comment: The only Ubuntu release still supported to upgrade to 12.04 is 10.04. server. All other releases reached end of life: http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release

Answer (score 0):

Are you upgrading to 13.04?

Try to boot on the 13.04-cd/usb, and click "Install Ubuntu".
You will get a few options about installing/upgrading. Click the Upgrade one.
It will keep your personal files, but reinstall the default apps.